# Error in porting lenovo k4 note A7010a48 to Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, porting

I started porting Ubuntu Touch to Lenovo k4 note two days ago. Everything worked fine till the breakfast command (ofc I had many errors along the way but somehow fixed them.) Now running the `mka halium-boot` command throws this error:

What and where is the problem?
Btw, it threw this error previously:

```
ccache: FATAL: /home/strtsnm/halium/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linaro-linux-android-7.x-kernel-aospa/bin/aarch64-linaro-linux-android-gcc: execv returned (No such file or directory)
```

`aarch64-linaro-linux-android` stuff really didn't exist in that folder. So I changed the `BroadConfig.mk` file (in the `device/lenovo/A7010a48` folder) to the folder that existed in the prebuilt folder (`/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9`).